# “a specified logon session does not exist. it may already have been terminated” after i joined the device to azure active directory

Tags: azure, microsoft-office-365, file-sharing, entra-id, office365

"a specified logon session does not exist. it may already have been terminated" after i joined the device to azure active directory

-i can't access our shared folder in our server after i joined the device to azure AD and use office 365 account (Please see click the link below to see the error image for your reference), but if i use local administrator of the device i can access the file server using the credentials with no problem, please note that we don't have an premises active directory or GPO, kindly help me.

[a specified logon session does not exist. it may already have been terminated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SVYU.png)

Comment: Is this computer Azure AD joined or Hybrid Azure AD joined? Is this computer joined to your on premises AD?

Comment: only azure AD joined, not a hybrid azure ad joined.

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD joined devices and Office 365 user accounts don't have access or permissions to your on premises file server resources. You'll need to use a local account to access the file server.